# how to substring in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, substring

I'm very new to ruby, in fact I just read it today. But I need to do something quick in Ruby, suppose I have a string ABC=180000. What I want to do is remove the last two chars and makes it become 8 chars of string, so the above case result should be 00001800

in case the string ABC=AA000, the final result is 00000AA0

Could you guys tell me how to do this quickly?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please look at the [Ruby documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/), especially the [String docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html) and tell us what you have tried already.

Answer (score 1):

Untested as send from mobile:

```
"180000"[0...-2].rjust 8,"0"
```

Have a look at the docs: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html

Answer (score 1):

Use this,

```
a = "AAA000"
puts a[0..-3].rjust(8,"0")
```